# iPhone App calling WCF works in simulator, but not on device

Tags: iphone, wcf, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, monodevelop

I have created an iPhone and iPad app which gets data from a WCF service and fills the data on the `UITableView`. This works fine on the simulator, but when I upload the app to the device, the app crashes after browsing through few screens.

After extensive searching on the internet I tried many things, such as adding additional attributes in the iPhone build options "Additional mtouch arguments", using `GC.Collect()`,  removing the screens from the app, and removing the unnecessary objects.

Finally, I have found that the app is crashing when calling the WCF method. The code snippet I use for calling WCF is below:

```
//Calling WCF 
ServicesClient services = new ServicesClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new  
   EndpointAddress(ServiceConstants.EndPointAddress));                             

services.GetUserSelectionsCompleted += HandleServicesGetUserSelectionsCompleted; 

services.GetUserSelectionsAsync(userId,sessionId); 

// Event Handler 
void HandleServicesGetUserSelectionsCompleted (object sender, 
   GetUserSelectionsCompletedEventArgs e) 
   { 
   InvokeOnMainThread( delegate{ 
      try 
      { 
         if(e.Result.Result.Status==1) 
         { 
            userSelection = e.Result.UserSelection; 

            userData = new string[] {"Display Type:$" + userSelection.DisplayTypeText,"Dealers:$" +userSelection.DealerNames+"|"+userSelection.RegionID.ToString()}; 
                                            tblSettings.Source = new DataSource(this); 
                                            tblSettings.ReloadData(); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
               DisplayMessage(e.Result.Result.Message); 
            } 
            DisplayLoadingScreen(false); 
         } 
         catch(Exception) 
         { 
            DisplayMessage(ServiceConstants.ServerError); 
         } 
         finally 
         { 
            GC.Collect(); 
         } 
       }); 
    }
```

When I check the log created in the device, I get the following:

> Incident Identifier: 677E1EBD-CBDF-47CC-9E68-051DA5B7112C
>   CrashReporter Key:   aa634f751365297d388510b3be7e647b0231ca5d
>   Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
>   Process:         MyIphoneApplication [3030]
>   Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/D335F3FE-016A-4F6D-8078-2C8DE164DB36/MyIphoneApplication.app/MyIphoneApplication
>   Identifier:      MyIphoneApplication
>   Version:         ??? (???)
>   Code Type:       ARM (Native)
>   Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2011-06-02 11:24:55.712 +0100
>   OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
>   Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGABRT)
>   Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe6000010
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>   Thread 0 Crashed:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfea1c 0x35ded000 + 72220
>   1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed53b4 0x35ea2000 + 209844
>   2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ecdbf8 0x35ea2000 + 179192
>   3   MyIphoneApplication     0x0050e7b6 0x1000 + 5298102
>   4   MyIphoneApplication     0x005279b4 0x1000 + 5401012
>   5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ee0728 0x35ea2000 + 255784
>   6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed53b4 0x35ea2000 + 209844
>   7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ecdbf8 0x35ea2000 + 179192
>   8   MyIphoneApplication     0x005d9eea 0x1000 + 6131434
>   9   MyIphoneApplication     0x005d9f52 0x1000 + 6131538
>   10  MyIphoneApplication     0x004fa8f6 0x1000 + 5216502
>   11  MyIphoneApplication     0x0050ddd0 0x1000 + 5295568
>   12  MyIphoneApplication     0x0050e3aa 0x1000 + 5297066
>   13  MyIphoneApplication     0x005270ce 0x1000 + 5398734
>   14  MyIphoneApplication     0x0003be28 0x1000 + 241192
>   15  MyIphoneApplication     0x0003bc2a 0x1000 + 240682
>   16  MyIphoneApplication     0x00062a7c 0x1000 + 399996
>   17  MyIphoneApplication     0x000450a6 0x1000 + 278694
>   18  MyIphoneApplication     0x000450f6 0x1000 + 278774
>   19  MyIphoneApplication     0x004c5e34 0x1000 + 5000756
>   20  MyIphoneApplication     0x004bd280 0x1000 + 4964992
>   21  MyIphoneApplication     0x004c02f8 0x1000 + 4977400
>   22  MyIphoneApplication     0x00044b8c 0x1000 + 277388
>   23  MyIphoneApplication     0x004c04b2 0x1000 + 4977842
>   24  MyIphoneApplication     0x004c03e0 0x1000 + 4977632
>   25  MyIphoneApplication     0x004aa97e 0x1000 + 4888958
>   26  MyIphoneApplication     0x004aa8a8 0x1000 + 4888744
>   27  MyIphoneApplication     0x00368c38 0x1000 + 3570744
>   28  MyIphoneApplication     0x004fd442 0x1000 + 5227586
>   29  MyIphoneApplication     0x005980c2 0x1000 + 5861570
>   30  MyIphoneApplication     0x005ed904 0x1000 + 6211844
>   31  UIKit                           0x312c522c 0x31251000 + 475692
>   32  UIKit                           0x312c5186 0x31251000 + 475526
>   33  UIKit                           0x312c4a2c 0x31251000 + 473644
>   34  UIKit                           0x31349ce4 0x31251000 + 1019108
>   35  UIKit                           0x31349be0 0x31251000 + 1018848
>   36  CoreFoundation                  0x3115f56a 0x31151000 + 58730
>   37  UIKit                           0x3126dec2 0x31251000 + 118466
>   38  UIKit                           0x3126de62 0x31251000 + 118370
>   39  UIKit                           0x31349a84 0x31251000 + 1018500
>   40  CoreFoundation                  0x3115f56a 0x31151000 + 58730
>   41  UIKit                           0x3126dec2 0x31251000 + 118466
>   42  UIKit                           0x3126de62 0x31251000 + 118370
>   43  UIKit                           0x3126de34 0x31251000 + 118324
>   44  UIKit                           0x3126db86 0x31251000 + 117638
>   45  UIKit                           0x312a7bd2 0x31251000 + 355282
>   46  UIKit                           0x3134980e 0x31251000 + 1017870
>   47  CoreFoundation                  0x3115f56a 0x31151000 + 58730
>   48  UIKit                           0x3126dec2 0x31251000 + 118466
>   49  UIKit                           0x3126de62 0x31251000 + 118370
>   50  UIKit                           0x3126de34 0x31251000 + 118324
>   51  UIKit                           0x3126db86 0x31251000 + 117638
>   52  UIKit                           0x3126e41c 0x31251000 + 119836
>   53  UIKit                           0x3126cbee 0x31251000 + 113646
>   54  UIKit                           0x3126c568 0x31251000 + 111976
>   55  UIKit                           0x3125530c 0x31251000 + 17164
>   56  UIKit                           0x31254c4c 0x31251000 + 15436
>   57  GraphicsServices                0x30ad8e70 0x30ad4000 + 20080
>   58  CoreFoundation                  0x311c6a90 0x31151000 + 481936
>   59  CoreFoundation                  0x311c8838 0x31151000 + 489528
>   60  CoreFoundation                  0x311c9606 0x31151000 + 493062
>   61  CoreFoundation                  0x31159ebc 0x31151000 + 36540
>   62  CoreFoundation                  0x31159dc4 0x31151000 + 36292
>   63  GraphicsServices                0x30ad8418 0x30ad4000 + 17432
>   64  GraphicsServices                0x30ad84c4 0x30ad4000 + 17604
>   65  UIKit                           0x3127fd62 0x31251000 + 191842
>   66  UIKit                           0x3127d800 0x31251000 + 182272
>   67  MyIphoneApplication     0x000aaff8 0x1000 + 696312
>   68  MyIphoneApplication     0x000841b6 0x1000 + 537014
>   69  MyIphoneApplication     0x004a911e 0x1000 + 4882718
>   70  MyIphoneApplication     0x00368c38 0x1000 + 3570744
>   71  MyIphoneApplication     0x004fd442 0x1000 + 5227586
>   72  MyIphoneApplication     0x005980c2 0x1000 + 5861570
>   73  MyIphoneApplication     0x00599ec4 0x1000 + 5869252
>   74  MyIphoneApplication     0x00599514 0x1000 + 5866772
>   75  MyIphoneApplication     0x00502630 0x1000 + 5248560
>   76  MyIphoneApplication     0x004f99d2 0x1000 + 5212626
>   77  MyIphoneApplication     0x00002a9c 0x1000 + 6812
>
> Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
>   Thread 1:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfffbc 0x35ded000 + 77756
>   1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35ad0032 0x35aca000 + 24626
>   2   libdispatch.dylib               0x35ad103a 0x35aca000 + 28730
>   3   libdispatch.dylib               0x35ad05ea 0x35aca000 + 26090
>   4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed658a 0x35ea2000 + 214410
>   5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed6bbc 0x35ea2000 + 215996
>
> Thread 2 name:  WebThread
>   Thread 2:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfcc00 0x35ded000 + 64512
>   1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfc758 0x35ded000 + 63320
>   2   CoreFoundation                  0x311c72b8 0x31151000 + 484024
>   3   CoreFoundation                  0x311c9562 0x31151000 + 492898
>   4   CoreFoundation                  0x31159ebc 0x31151000 + 36540
>   5   CoreFoundation                  0x31159dc4 0x31151000 + 36292
>   6   WebCore                         0x367c227e 0x367bc000 + 25214
>   7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed530a 0x35ea2000 + 209674
>   8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed6bb4 0x35ea2000 + 215988
>
> Thread 3:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfcc50 0x35ded000 + 64592
>   1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfcf6e 0x35ded000 + 65390
>   2   VolvoDealerpointiDashboard      0x005d3d66 0x1000 + 6106470
>   3   VolvoDealerpointiDashboard      0x00552cce 0x1000 + 5577934
>   4   VolvoDealerpointiDashboard      0x005b33b4 0x1000 + 5972916
>   5   VolvoDealerpointiDashboard      0x005b3464 0x1000 + 5973092
>   6   VolvoDealerpointiDashboard      0x005cb098 0x1000 + 6070424
>   7   VolvoDealerpointiDashboard      0x005e9250 0x1000 + 6193744
>   8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed530a 0x35ea2000 + 209674
>   9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed6bb4 0x35ea2000 + 215988
>
> Thread 4:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfed18 0x35ded000 + 72984
>   1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ea44ac 0x35ea2000 + 9388
>   2   MyIphoneApplication     0x005cbc1c 0x1000 + 6073372
>   3   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b0082 0x1000 + 5959810
>   4   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b33b4 0x1000 + 5972916
>   5   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b3464 0x1000 + 5973092
>   6   MyIphoneApplication     0x005cb098 0x1000 + 6070424
>   7   MyIphoneApplication     0x005e9250 0x1000 + 6193744
>   8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed530a 0x35ea2000 + 209674
>   9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed6bb4 0x35ea2000 + 215988
>
> Thread 5:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfcc68 0x35ded000 + 64616
>   1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfcf62 0x35ded000 + 65378
>   2   MyIphoneApplication     0x005d3cfe 0x1000 + 6106366
>   3   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b1ae4 0x1000 + 5966564
>   4   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b33b4 0x1000 + 5972916
>   5   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b3464 0x1000 + 5973092
>   6   MyIphoneApplication     0x005cb098 0x1000 + 6070424
>   7   MyIphoneApplication     0x005e9250 0x1000 + 6193744
>   8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed530a 0x35ea2000 + 209674
>   9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed6bb4 0x35ea2000 + 215988
>
> Thread 6:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfffbc 0x35ded000 + 77756
>   1   MyIphoneApplication     0x005aeac2 0x1000 + 5954242
>   2   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b33b4 0x1000 + 5972916
>   3   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b3464 0x1000 + 5973092
>   4   MyIphoneApplication     0x005cb098 0x1000 + 6070424
>   5   MyIphoneApplication     0x005e9250 0x1000 + 6193744
>   6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed530a 0x35ea2000 + 209674
>   7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed6bb4 0x35ea2000 + 215988
>
> Thread 7:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfcc68 0x35ded000 + 64616
>   1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35dfcf62 0x35ded000 + 65378
>   2   MyIphoneApplication     0x005d3cfe 0x1000 + 6106366
>   3   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b1ae4 0x1000 + 5966564
>   4   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b33b4 0x1000 + 5972916
>   5   MyIphoneApplication     0x005b3464 0x1000 + 5973092
>   6   MyIphoneApplication     0x005cb098 0x1000 + 6070424
>   7   MyIphoneApplication     0x005e9250 0x1000 + 6193744
>   8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed530a 0x35ea2000 + 209674
>   9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed6bb4 0x35ea2000 + 215988
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
>       r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
>       r4: 0x3f59d48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x00695190      r7: 0x2fdfc9f0
>       r8: 0x08254970    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x0813c220
>       ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfc9e4      lr: 0x35ed53bb      pc: 0x35dfea1c
>     cpsr: 0x00000010
>
> Binary Images:
>       0x1000 -   0x673fff + MyIphoneApplication armv7  <202c2ba89a493f5a981ab6fb05952cfa> /var/mobile/Applications/D335F3FE-016A-4F6D-8078-2C8DE164DB36/Volvo.Dealerpoint.iDashboard.app/VolvoDealerpointiDashboard
>   0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7   /usr/lib/dyld
>   0x30874000 - 0x3089dfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
>   0x3089e000 - 0x308d5fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
>   0x308d6000 - 0x308d7fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
>   0x30934000 - 0x30934fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
>   0x30a32000 - 0x30ac7fff  ImageIO armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
>   0x30ad4000 - 0x30ae0fff  GraphicsServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
>   0x30c3f000 - 0x30c41fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
>   0x30c42000 - 0x30d5cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
>   0x30f19000 - 0x30f19fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
>   0x30f56000 - 0x30f93fff  CoreText armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
>   0x31151000 - 0x31236fff  CoreFoundation armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   0x31251000 - 0x315defff  UIKit armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>   0x315ff000 - 0x316ecfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
>   0x316ed000 - 0x316eefff  libremovefile.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
>   0x316ff000 - 0x31708fff  CoreVideo armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
>   0x31759000 - 0x3175bfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
>   0x3175c000 - 0x317adfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x317c7000 - 0x317cefff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
>   0x31813000 - 0x31818fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
>   0x31853000 - 0x3185efff  libz.1.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
>   0x319cf000 - 0x319cffff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
>   0x319d0000 - 0x319d1fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
>   0x319d2000 - 0x319f2fff  PrintKit armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
>   0x319ff000 - 0x31a41fff  CoreAudio armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
>   0x32014000 - 0x3204cfff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
>   0x3208d000 - 0x320c9fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
>   0x320f4000 - 0x33b42fff  TextInput armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
>   0x33c8f000 - 0x33c94fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
>   0x33dac000 - 0x33df2fff  CoreTelephony armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
>   0x33df3000 - 0x33dfffff  SpringBoardServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
>   0x33ed4000 - 0x33ed6fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
>   0x33ed7000 - 0x33edcfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
>   0x33fc8000 - 0x33fccfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
>   0x34102000 - 0x34106fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   0x34108000 - 0x341b9fff  WebKit armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
>   0x341ba000 - 0x341c7fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
>   0x342a0000 - 0x342a6fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
>   0x34581000 - 0x34582fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
>   0x345ef000 - 0x345f2fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
>   0x345f3000 - 0x34608fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
>   0x3480f000 - 0x34812fff  IOSurface armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
>   0x34913000 - 0x34972fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
>   0x34a22000 - 0x34b41fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
>   0x34c0e000 - 0x34cbdfff  QuartzCore armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
>   0x34d06000 - 0x34dcafff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x34fb0000 - 0x34fe3fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
>   0x34fe4000 - 0x34febfff  AggregateDictionary armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
>   0x34fee000 - 0x3510ffff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x35150000 - 0x3543dfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
>   0x35469000 - 0x3549efff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
>   0x3549f000 - 0x3555efff  CFNetwork armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
>   0x3555f000 - 0x35578fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
>   0x35699000 - 0x357edfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
>   0x3588e000 - 0x3588ffff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
>   0x35894000 - 0x3593dfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
>   0x35968000 - 0x3596dfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
>   0x35a5b000 - 0x35a78fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
>   0x35ac5000 - 0x35ac9fff  libcache.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
>   0x35aca000 - 0x35ad7fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
>   0x35b08000 - 0x35b47fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>   0x35b48000 - 0x35b48fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
>   0x35be7000 - 0x35c56fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
>   0x35c57000 - 0x35cacfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
>   0x35cba000 - 0x35de6fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
>   0x35ded000 - 0x35e04fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
>   0x35e53000 - 0x35e9dfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>   0x35e9e000 - 0x35ea0fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
>   0x35ea2000 - 0x35f23fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x35f24000 - 0x35f5cfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
>   0x36388000 - 0x3648cfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
>   0x364ea000 - 0x36509fff  Bom armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
>   0x367bc000 - 0x36dc7fff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
>   0x36e9c000 - 0x36ecbfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
>   0x36ed5000 - 0x36ee3fff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
>   0x36ef6000 - 0x36efbfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
>   0x36ffe000 - 0x36ffefff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/

Since I am using C#/.NET I am assuming that the code is managed code and properly garbage collected. Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: just stepping aside, you ever though of using 'wsdl2objc' mac app to do all the hard work of calling the web service for you. if this applies of course. Dealing with it yourself is not only long, but also asking for trouble if you have not long began coding away

Comment: How is your iPhone connecting to the internet?  You need to figure out what's different in the way that your iPhone is attempting to make the call compared to the simulator.  Is the computer with the simulator on wifi and the iPhone on 3G?

Comment: I am connecting to the internet via wifi for both compute and iphone device. This problem was not existing 3 months ago when i was using the previous version of monotouch framework(3.2.6 i guess). I have downloaded the latest updates which prompts when we open the monodevelop ide, and the version of the framework now is 4.0.3. Now i am unable to revert back to check with the previous framework and i dont have it on my computer. Did someone face such problem earlier

Comment: Add tags for mono development.  Maybe an expert in that can help...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this happen after the webservice has been called 10 times?

Comment: Try stepping through it to find the exact line it crashes.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800643/latest-monotouch-4-0-problem-when-trying-to-access-a-wcf-service
 Smells like the same issue.